# Oozie with Hadoop 2, Job hangs in "RUNNING"

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hadoop-yarn

I have workflow job with a java action node. Run with Hadoop 2.1.0.2.0.4.0-38 and Oozie 3.3.2.2.0.4.0
When I submit the job I see 2 lines in Hadoop Resource Manager screen.
1. with original job name
2. with Oozie job name.

The task with Oozie job name is hanging in "RUNNING" state
The task with original name is in "Accepted" state.
All that I see in logs is:

```
     >>> Invoking Main class now >>>
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems that number of maptasks that can run in parallel are limited. Set the below property to a value higher than current value.

mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum
50

This might fix your issue.

Thanks,
Sathish.